# How to find trigonometry values using triangles in 1/2 form?

Tags: trigonometry

How to find trigonometry values using triangles?
 I only know how to find values of 30, 60, 45 degree using triangle ( in 1/2 form ).
Is there is any way to find values of angle 40, 90, 120,180, 360 in 1/2 form.

My calculator give me answer in points but i need answer in 1/2 form. Is there is any way to find out values using triangle like we find for 30,60, 45?

Comment: I am afraid you are asking this on the wrong site. This site is for the software product MathematicA. It is not about MathematicS.

Comment: sorry, i thought its about mathematics , any other website available for mathematics in stackexchange?

Comment: thanks you are really helpful person.